# How to pass a branch name to jenkins pipeline for hook defined for git under tfs

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs

I wan to define a hook for git repo under tfs.
The "hook" starts a jenkins file pipeline.
I want to pass as a parameter the braanch name that triggered the hook to tfs, there is a section to pass a parameter but i am really dont understand how to do that?
[image]
Which variable on tfs receives the branch name ?

Comment: Hi. What plugin are you using in jenkins? In another way, when you share screenshots be careful with private data like links, users, passwords. You can erase it before share it.

Comment: Hi
The images are from public blog :)
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/25/vsts-visual-studio-team-services-integration-with-jenkins/

Which plug in i should use for git tfs builds ?

Comment: Oks. How are you integrating your tfs with jenkins? Do you know about devops?

Comment: The only thing that i need to know is which tfs system var passes to jenkins the branch name, such as in integration with git lab i have GIT_BRANCH parameter 
And yes i do know DevOps
TFS is new for me

Comment: If you want to understand how parameters are sent from TFS to Jenkins, you need to research about **webhooks and devops**. You could check my post https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks